# How to create a flower like structure in css and html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an image like the following using a combination of HTML and CSS, but I can't seem to get the 'petals' to rotate around the middle.

[image]

Here is my code:

```css
.flower{
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 20px;
  display:  flex;
  align-items:  center;
  justify-content:  center;
  position:  relative;
}

.mid{
  width:  200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius:  50%;
  background: #35414d;
  z-index:  4;
}

.petal{
  position:  absolute;
  left: 40px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:  #b5a9d4;
}

.petal.p1 {
  transform: rotate(22.5deg);
   z-index: 5;
}

.petal.p2 {
  transform: rotate(50deg);
   z-index: 5;
}

.petal.p3 {
  transform: rotate(100deg);
   z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="flower" >
<div class="mid"></div>
  <div class="petal p1"></div>
  <div class="petal p2"></div>
  <div class="petal p3"></div>
  <div class="petal p4"></div>
  <div class="petal p5"></div>
  <div class="petal p6"></div>
  <div class="petal p7"></div>
  <div class="petal p8"></div>
</div>
```

What transform values would work best to get 8 petals to surround the center circle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `transform-origin` of each petal to the centre of the flower. The [transform origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) is the point around which each petal will be rotated. So if you place all your petals on the flower's edge, and set the transform origin to the centre, when you apply `transform: rotate()` to each petal, they will be rotated around the edges of the flower.

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
.center {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 999px;
  background-color: rgba(20, 30, 255, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.petal {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 999px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: rgba(20, 30, 255, 0.5);
  transform-origin: center 150px;
}
.petal:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.petal:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.petal:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
.petal:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.petal:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}
.petal:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
.petal:nth-child(7) {
  transform: rotate(315deg);
}
.petal:nth-child(8) {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">  
  <div class="petal"></div>
  <div class="petal"></div>
  <div class="petal"></div>
  <div class="petal"></div>
  <div class="petal"></div>
  <div class="petal"></div>
  <div class="petal"></div>
  <div class="petal"></div>
  
  <div class="center"></div>
</div>
```

EDIT TO ADD

Performing a `transform: rotate()` will rotate the petal itself, and any content in the petal element. If the content should not be rotated then, instead of rotating the petals around the flower's centre, the position of each petal must be calculated with trigonometry.

8 equally spaced petals are, in fact, quite easy to do as they are positioned at multiples of 45°.

In the example, the centre of the flower is at `top: 50%` and `left: 50%`. The radius of the flower centre is `100px`, and by using the Pythagorean theorem, we can calculate `71px` left and up from the flower's centre will be the point 45° on it's circumference. To place the petal's centre we also need to take into account the petal's width, which is `50px`.

A full example of all petals would look like:

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
.center {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 999px;
  background-color: rgba(20, 30, 255, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.petal {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 999px;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgba(20, 30, 255, 0.5);
}
.petal:nth-child(1) {
  top: calc(50% - 71px - 50px);
  left: calc(50% + 71px - 50px);
}
.petal:nth-child(2) {
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  left: calc(50% + 100px - 50px);
}
.petal:nth-child(3) {
  top: calc(50% + 71px - 50px);
  left: calc(50% + 71px - 50px);
}
.petal:nth-child(4) {
  top: calc(50% + 100px - 50px);
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
}
.petal:nth-child(5) {
  top: calc(50% + 71px - 50px);
  left: calc(50% - 71px - 50px);
}
.petal:nth-child(6) {
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  left: calc(50% - 100px - 50px);
}
.petal:nth-child(7) {
  top: calc(50% - 71px - 50px);
  left: calc(50% - 71px - 50px);
}
.petal:nth-child(8) {
  top: calc(50% - 100px - 50px);
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">  
  <div class="petal">petal 1</div>
  <div class="petal">petal 2</div>
  <div class="petal">petal 3</div>
  <div class="petal">petal 4</div>
  <div class="petal">petal 5</div>
  <div class="petal">petal 6</div>
  <div class="petal">petal 7</div>
  <div class="petal">petal 8</div>
  
  <div class="center"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! I fear the transforming is beyond my current depths of understanding. It appears as though the "petal" elements are upside down, so as I go to add links/text to them the text appears upside down. Any advice on how to get text added right side up and centered in the middle of each petal?

Comment: @KourtneyKearney edited answer to not use rotate so that text remains upright

Answer (score 0):

Make 8 copies of a `.mid` and a `.petal` within it. Then position the `.mid`s on top of each other with `z-index` 1 to 8. Next rotate each `.mid` `45deg` progressively (ex. 0, 45, 90,... 315).

```css
.flower {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 96vw;
  height: 600px;
  padding: 20px;
}

section {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.stem {
  background: #35414d;
}

.petal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 180px;
  left: calc(50% - 60px);
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgba(181, 169, 212, 0.5);
}

.m1 {
  z-index: 1;
}

.m2 {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: 2;
}

.m3 {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  z-index: 3;
}

.m4 {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  z-index: 4;
}

.m5 {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  z-index: 5;
}

.m6 {
  transform: rotate(225deg);
  z-index: 6;
}

.m7 {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  z-index: 7;
}

.m8 {
  transform: rotate(315deg);
  z-index: 8;
}
```

```html
<div class="flower">
  <section class="mid stem"></section>
  <section class="mid m1">
    <div class="petal"></div>
  </section>
  <section class="mid m2">
    <div class="petal"></div>
  </section>
  <section class="mid m3">
    <div class="petal"></div>
  </section>
  <section class="mid m4">
    <div class="petal"></div>
  </section>
  <section class="mid m5">
    <div class="petal"></div>
  </section>
  <section class="mid m6">
    <div class="petal"></div>
  </section>
  <section class="mid m7">
    <div class="petal"></div>
  </section>
  <section class="mid m8">
    <div class="petal"></div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are up for an easy solution you can rely on one element and gradients to achieve the result.

Adjust the `30% 30%` in the code to control the size of the small circle and the percentage of the gradient applied to the main element to control the size of the big circle.

```css
.flower {
  --c: rgb(255 0 0/50%); /* the color */
  width: 300px; /* the size */
  
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  display: grid;
  background: radial-gradient(var(--c) 45%,#0000 46%);
  overflow: hidden;
}
.flower::before,
.flower::after {
  content:"";
  grid-area: 1/1;
  --_g:/30% 30% radial-gradient(var(--c) 71%,#0000 72%) no-repeat;
  background:
   top  var(--_g),bottom var(--_g),
   left var(--_g),right  var(--_g);
}
.flower::after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}


body {
 margin: 0;
 min-height: 100vh;
 display: grid;
 place-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flower"></div>
```